# Working with shortcodes on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

iam recent download a Wordpress theme called The Gossip, this theme has a shortcode function that help you to create different things, for example lets just say i want to display the LAST 5 posts from the category Gadgets on my Sidebar, all that i have to do, is to paste that code

```
[posts cats="gadgets" images="true" image_width="80" image_height="80" title="true" per_page="5" cols="1" image_wrap="true" pagination="false" meta="false" read_more="false" title_size="14" name='"sidebardog" content="post" content_display="excerpt" excerpt_length="0" spacing="spacing-small"]
```

and the theme does the rest, my question is, how can a make a code to display the last 5 posts from the same category of the current post. I am tried to replace **cats="gadgets"** for **cats="the_category();"** or **cats=""** but it didn't worked.

Anybody has any ideas on how to correctly do that? Thanks alot for the attention, any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

in functions.php you should find the following line:

```
add_shortcode( 'posts', 'YOUR_SHORTCODE_FUNCTION_NAME' );
```

then you just have to search for YOUR_SHORTCODE_FUNCTION and inside it get category using global $post variable